# How to automatically import external images on blogspot

Tags: blogger, blogspot

i have a blogspot. I'm always copy images from other blogs. And i only have method : save it (image) to my computer and upload it in blogger editor.

I see the wordpress have plugin automatically import external images to library (host on wordpress). Now I want a way to do it with blogspot. When i click **Post** in **Post Editor** : All external images automatically upload to blogger and hosted on google such as url:

https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-kFISeyzwNp0/WG9xA1aUrsI/AAAAAAAAAeA/ITMC__2wl6YkP_01LnbdOyIpVj_7s6i4wCLcB/s1600/b1.jpg

I wonder google API can do this ? Or creating a tool in hosting can do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry But blogger has its own limitations..Its not possible on blogger/blogspot platform.. you have to do it manually!